# Modules variables as a file

Tags: terraform

I have a `terraform module` that looks like below

```
module "newserver" {
  source = "./newserver"

  // passing the variables here
}
```

Instead of passing the variables there, can i pass them as a file in the command like below
`terraform apply -var-file="/path/variables.tfvars"`
When i do that, i am getting errors like `missing required argument`, what am i missing here, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: it is fine you are trying to pass variable file from command line, but this module expects a variable (from your question and comments in the module import code), so pass the value that you obtain from `variables.tfvars` file.

Comment: @JBone sorry i dont get you, any examples please

Comment: You would have to declare the variables again in a similar or equivalent declaration as inside your module(s), and then assign the inputs to the variables to the values of your root module variable inputs. If you find yourself having to do this a lot, then you should probably re-architect to best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module has variables defined inside it with `variable` blocks such as

```
variable "example_var" {}
```

When you instantiate the module, you'll need to pass the required variable into the module. If you want to pass variables into the module when you instantiate it, you'll also have to define those variables as well

```
module "newserver" {
  source = "./newserver"

  example_var = var.example_var
}

variable "example_var" {}
```

Terraform is scoped so that variables are scoped inside of modules, you'll have to make a new variable if you instantiate a module and want to pass variables into it

Comment: `variables.tf` of that module has variables in it, in `main.tf` i am calling the module, so inside that again i need to call it?

Comment: the `variables.tf` inside of the module is scoped to the module. those become the inputs for the module

if you instantiate the module and want to use variables as inputs, you'll need new variables in the scope where the module is instantiated